# Searching data of excel using row and column Index

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledb

**Format of excel:**

[image: Excel]

**Code Sample:**

```
 var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + excelSheetName + "$]", connectionString);
 var ds = new DataSet();
 adapter.Fill(ds, "GridInfo");
 DataTable data = ds.Tables["GridInfo"];            
 string returnValue = string.Format("{0:n0}", data.Rows[row][column]);
 return returnValue;
```

How can i access any value in excel providing row and column header values (like p, a) in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set PrimaryKey properties for DataTable just use Find() method. For example:

```
//Set Primary Key for DataTable
data.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { data.Columns[0] };

//And use Find Method
var myValue = data.Rows.Find("p")["a"];
var myValue2 = data.Rows.Find("q")["c"];
var myValue3 = data.Rows.Find("r")["b"];
```

Regards Grzegorz Kotfis